# placeholder for tagit input field

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, tag-it

I am using [tagit plugin](http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/) for tagging and bootstrap for design in my website. I want to show placeholder text in the tagit input field.

Already tried:

`$("#input_id").tagit({placeholder: 'placeholder text'})`

But, it  is not showing "placeholder text" as default text in tagit input field.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Its solved, i was setting the wrong attribute.
Instead

```
$("#input_id").tagit({placeholder: 'placeholder text'})
```

it should be

```
$("#input_id").tagit({placeholderText: 'placeholder text'})
```

Answer (score 0):

HI now you can try to javascript as like this

[**setAttribute()**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp) Method

```js
var rohit = document.getElementById('input_id');
rohit.setAttribute("placeholder", "placeholder text");
```

```html
<input id="input_id" type="text" >
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show placeholder once use simple: 
 `$("#input_id").tagit({placeholderText: 'Placeholder text'});`

or if you want change one dynamic - use: 
`$("#input_id").data("ui-tagit").tagInput.attr("placeholder", "New placeholder text");`